# Want to run python script and Flask api from single Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, gunicorn

I am trying to create container with following docker file. Since it is going to execute last CMD, it ignores `CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 run_scheduler.py --config=${config}"]`.
Is there a way to run both from single docker file. Also, is it possible to pass `${config}` argument to flask api in `CMD ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "run_api:application", "&"]`

```
FROM python:3.8

LABEL version="0.1"

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

ARG config=dev
RUN  pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["sh", "-c", "python3 run_scheduler.py --config=${config}"]
CMD ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "run_api:application", "&"]
```

Comment: Check out this SO Post: https://serverfault.com/questions/685697/multiple-commands-in-docker-cmd-directive

Comment: You can specify an alternate command when you run the container (after the image name in `docker run`; as a Docker Compose `command:`).  Run two separate containers with two separate commands.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments you can pass 2-line bash script in CMD. This can cause problems however. Docker is not really meant to run multiple processes in single container. I already see "&" argument in your second CMD. I guess you had problems with second process wasn't running so you tried to push it to the background.

The solution recommended by Docker is to run `supervisord` inside the container: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/

From naming concepts I guess you can solve your problem with Flask-APScheduler https://github.com/viniciuschiele/flask-apscheduler
This way you can get rid of second sidecar script.

And lastly you asked:

> Also, is it possible to pass ${config} argument to flask api

and answer is yes. Declare `ENV` in your Dockerfile like so:

```
FROM python:3.8
...
...
ENV config foo
...
CMD ["whatever_command", "--option", "${config}"]
```

This way `"${config}"` will be replaced with value `foo`.

Comment: Thanks for help. I did create 2 containers. Worked for my use case.using following docker compose.                                                                                                                 
 ```version: '3'
services:
  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "run_api:application", "&"]
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
  scheduler:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ["sh", "-c", "python3 run_scheduler.py --config=dev"]
    ports:
      - "80:80"  ```

Comment: I also need to pass --config=dev to command: ["gunicorn",  "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000",  "run_api:application", "&"] . This variable I need to use to pick config in Flask Api.  I know that I can pass this as an arg from command but how can I access in my flask api (run_api: application).

Comment: You need to use os module: `from os import getenv` and use `getenv` to pick up your env var. Have a look at https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.getenv

Comment: Thanks,  "from os import getenv and use getenv" did solve the issue.